# Coroutine wait for method before going on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a coroutine that downloads a video, writes it into the memory and then, plays it.

```
IEnumerator DownloadVideo(string url) {
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    byte[] result = www.downloadHandler.data;
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, result);
    StartCoroutine(PlayVideo(path, 3));
}

IEnumerator PlayVideo(string url, float delayTime = 0) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);
    player.url = url;        
    player.Prepare();        
    while (!player.isPrepared) yield return null;
    player.Play();
}
```

The problem is that I have to set this argument `delayTime` in the `PlayVideo` coroutine, because `File.WriteAllBytes(path, result)` takes a while to finish and if I start playing the video immediatly, it won't play correctly.

The question is simple: in the coroutine `DownloadVideo`, how can I wait until `File.WriteAllBytes(path, result)` finish to call `StartCoroutine(PlayVideo(path))`?

Comment: Just wait for the video to download first.  When the video id done download, then enable the play video

Comment: Btw, there's no reason to call `StartCoroutine` from within a coroutine. You can just `yield return PlayVideo(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using `File.WriteAllBytesAsync` (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytesasync?view=netcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8)).

Then you can call `await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, result)`. You will also need to make your `DownloadVideo` function asynchronous. Essentially the `await` says, wait until this call is done until I move onward in this function.

More details about asynchronous programming in C# can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: I'm afraid Unity doesn't include the method `WriteAllBytesAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not closing the file.

`File.WriteAllBytes(path, result);` is not an async call so it should finish its work before going to the next line which is starting `PlayVideo` coroutine.

I would recommend you use [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-3.5) and make sure to dispose of the stream before calling the `PlayVideo` coroutine.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems to be working:

```
IEnumerator DownloadVideo(string url) {
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    byte[] result = www.downloadHandler.data;
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, result);
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => File.Exists(path));
    StartCoroutine(PlayVideo(path));
}
```

Apparently `File.Exists(path)` will only return true when `WriteAllBytes(path, result)` is over.

Answer (score 0):

File.WriteAllBytes is a synchronous method, so it is not an issue with your code. File.WriteAllBytes does not take additional time to finish when that line of code is done executing. It is probable that you have another process locking the file like an antivirus or a backup software.

Comment: I thought the same thing but the solution I found initially was to delay the execution of the VideoPlayer, but with the workaround I mentioned, it seems to work correctly.